# Gaussian random variable over multiple periods

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, discrete-time

Let's assume that :
$$X_0=X_0$$
$$X_1=(1+R_1)*X_0$$
$$...$$
$$X_N=(1+R_N)*X_{N-1}$$
where $R_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,u^2)$.

I am trying to compute the probability $P(X_N < a)$.
How accurate is it to assume that $$X_N=(1+S_N)*X_{0}$$ where $S \sim \mathcal{N}(0,u^2N)$ ?

Comment: is $X_0$ random? Are the $R_i$ independent?

Comment: Yes. $X_0$ is fixed and the $R_i$ are independent.

Comment: I'm guessing this is going to be really hard to say much about in total generality, although i don't know for sure. This comes down to products of Gaussian RVs which are tricky to study. I'm skeptical that your estimate is very good, as the actual quantity will be $P_N X_0$ where $P_N$ is a product of $N$ $\mathcal N(1, u^2)$ iid Gaussians, and has 2nd moment $E(P_N^2) = (u^2 + 1)^N$ which is exponentially more than the 2nd moment of $S_N$. This paper discusses products of gaussians and might be interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10516